# Global Search not working for Custom Object

Tags: global-search

I'm working on an issue where Global Search was not working for Custom Objects. I was able to get most of them working by creating tabs for the Custom Objects and making them visible through permission sets. However, after doing this for one Custom Object, it is still not coming up with results when searching. The only difference between this one and the others that I can see is that the Name is not Auto Number; it is Text. Is that a thing? Any ideas on what else to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I want to link to documentation. I encountered this too, in an organization that no one had used in over 6 months! No records would appear. The Global Search algorithm needed to be "trained".

From: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385930&type=1

> Global Search keeps track of which objects you use and how often you use them. It also arranges the search results accordingly. Results for the object you use most frequently appear at the top of the list. Keeping this in mind, the following are possible:
>
> The object the affected User is looking for is not an object they interact on a regular basis. This makes it a low-priority on search results, thus it might not show up in the top search results. For more details review the Objects displayed in search results inconsistent between users article.

Answer (score 0):

So the configuration was correct for the rogue custom object. In order to see results come up in Global Search, you need to have opened a few of the records. It returns only records that you have viewed I guess.